# What is most efficient way to get the PID of the process that is using a file on Linux

Tags: files, kernel, process

Let's say I have a file which I want to query on demand to check which process is currently accessing is (opened). Going through all PIDs in `/proc/{PID}/fd` seems resource intensive, Is there any alternative way to accomplish the same?

Comment: Do you need to check for processes which may not have exited cleanly? From memory on a RHEL based 3.10 series Kernel have previously found that if the main thread of a PID exits, but other thread(s) in the process have not exited, then searching just ``/proc/{PID}/fd`` didn't find the files still open by the process in which the main thread had exited. Had to perform a recursive search following ``/proc/{PID}/task/{TID}/fd`` to reliably find all processes which still had a file open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tools to do it for you: [`fuser`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fuser.html) (just outputs the PIDs) and [`lsof`](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof) (lots of options and fancy output).

> Going through all PIDs in /proc/{PID}/fd seems resource intensive

It's the only way anyway on Linux. There's no system call to query which processes have a file open. But don't do it yourself — if only because `/proc/{PID}/fd` is only about open files in the strict sense, and doesn't list other cases such as memory-mapped files, open directories, etc.

Note that this means you cannot know about processes running as other users¹ that might have the file open, even if you own the file, unless you do the lookup as root. (But if no other user can even see the file, and this has been true since the file was created or the system rebooted, you know there are no such processes.)

¹  <sub>More generally, processes that you don't have control over, which can include other cases such as processes running in a different namespace or with extra privileges.</sub>

Comment: Note that `lsof` also checks `/proc/pid/maps` (whose contents cannot be parsed reliably), `/proc/pid/cwd` and `/proc/pid/root`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the final parenthetical is not entirely accurate. Unless your system is using an LSM to enforce mandatory access controls, the root user could open such a file, and by extension anything started as root that then drops privileges to a non-root user could have the file open.

Answer (score 4):

Use `lsof`.

For example:

```
[root@nagios01 objects]# lsof /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
mysqld  17699 mysql    9uW  REG    8,3  5242880 4850251 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
```

Another example:

```
merlin@uc-s4m75657:~/Experiments/test_ifxr$ lsof -a .
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash     8646 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
bash     9261 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
ssh     37456 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
bash    38639 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
lsof    38679 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
lsof    38680 merlin  cwd    DIR  254,2     4096 421348 .
```

As you see, in this case the "current directory" (which is where the dot refers to) is claimed by six processes.

Last example also shows that it might be not "the PID", but several PIDs at once. Another such example will be PostgreSQL data files, which are often simultaneously read by several worker processes.

Notice if you opened a file in an editor it is not the fact it will show up in lsof output. For instance, editor may cache the file and only touch it during open/save operation, when it will be seen in lsof; all the other time it won't.

Comment: See also `lsof -t` if you only need the pids.

Comment: Doesn't `lsof` do just the same, scan `/proc/xxx/fd` and `/proc/xxx/task/yyy/fd`, as was described by OP?

Comment: Yes. there is no other way to do it in Linux. I though the OP was going to re-implement lsof (because they didn't mentioned it), which is of course the wrong way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment on the question about *Do you need to check for processes which may not have exited cleanly?* created some test code to investigate.

[partial_thread_exit.adb](https://github.com/Chester-Gillon/ibv_message_passing/blob/master/ibv_message_passing_ada_project/source/partial_thread_exit/partial_thread_exit.adb) is the source of a program which can cause the main thread to exit, while leaving another thread running.

[find_processes_using_file.c](https://github.com/Chester-Gillon/ibv_message_passing/blob/master/ibv_message_passing_c_project/source/find_processes_using_file/find_processes_using_file.c) is the source of `lsof` like program which can scan for references to a filename. From a command line option can either:

1. Search by PID by iterating over `/proc/<pid>/fd`
2. Search by TID by iterating over `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/fd`

Started two instances of the `partial_thread_exit` test harness, which leaves open a file named `/dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE`. The first instance was left with the main and other thread running:

```
$ ./partial_thread_exit 
Blocker_Task tid 17995 running in pid 17994
Main thread in pid 17994 - press return to exit main thread only
```

The second instance was left so that only the other thread was running, i.e. the main thread had exited:

```
$ ./partial_thread_exit 
Blocker_Task tid 13435 running in pid 13434
Main thread in pid 13434 - press return to exit main thread only

Main thread exiting...
```

If run to search by PID then only finds the process in which the main thread is running, regardless if run as normal user or root:

```
$ time ./find_processes_using_file /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/17994/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE

num_filenames_compared=2532 num_eacces_errors=260

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.015s
```

```
$ time sudo ./find_processes_using_file /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/17994/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE

num_filenames_compared=3435 num_eacces_errors=0

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.011s
sys 0m0.031s
```

Whereas if run to search by TID (by using the `-t` option) then finds both the process with main thread and the one in which the main thread had exited, regardless if run as normal user or root:

```
$ time ./find_processes_using_file -t /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/13434/task/13435/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/17994/task/17994/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE

num_filenames_compared=68327 num_eacces_errors=317

real    0m0.254s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.217s
```

```
$ time sudo ./find_processes_using_file -t /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/13434/task/13435/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE
/proc/17994/task/17994/fd/3 -> /dev/shm/IBV_MESSAGE_BW_IN_USE

num_filenames_compared=69500 num_eacces_errors=0

real    0m0.280s
user    0m0.048s
sys 0m0.228s
```

As expected, searching by TID is slower than searching by PID as indicated by:

1. More real time reported by `time`
2. A larger value of `num_filenames_compared` reported which is how many files opened by PIDs/TIDs which had to be matched.

Obviously, the absolute difference between the two will vary according to the total number on TIDs/PIDs running in the system.

The value of `num_eacces_errors` is non-zero when run as a normal user, when attempts to open a `fd` directory for a PID/TID failed with `EACCES`. I.e. how many times didn't have permission to find which files were open by a process.

Answer (score -1):

There is one very raw way considering there is no direct way from kernel for it. In filesystem on storage for every file, process references which can be pid and count of references should be created which involves modifying struct inode. However that  will involve modifying open system call and close system call which will respectively populate and eliminate the reference and count. struct inode currently maintains timestamps like last access and last modified timestamp and same can be traced to achieve this. After which a system call like fstat can be modified to return this process reference. This has drawbacks like filesystem and kernel system call has to be modified. Depending on your target in case is embedded device this can be feasible. Reference changes through open and close calls most likely will need synchronisation. This is definitely not feasible unless in rare case. This will also involve kernel upgrades patched for this. There can be some considerations like if too many processes are accessing file and reference list will be big. Those are application related issues.

Comment: Did a neural network (ChatGPT) write this? While packed with information, this looks extremely convoluted, requiring very deep knowledge of the kernel, has a very high probability of introducing bugs, and actually does not answer the question.

Comment: it is not ai software answer, i wrote it. I implemented similar kind of functionality and not system call though for socket in kernel modifying socket buffer structure. These are sort of common modifications in kernel and many developers in many companies do that with quite customised linux kernel. linux kernel is quite reliable and well written and you can easily get hold and make changes to it for certain features needed.  Though i was doubtful if it is just cmdline based solution required though kernel tag is used and i gave dev oriented approach.